# Translating C pointer statements to their C# equivalent

Tags: c#, c

I have some C code I am trying to translate into C# code and I'm running into pointers which I am not familiar with so I don't know the C# equivalent.  Get I get some help?

Case 1: Given these three lines in C, how do I declare p in C#?

```
double snorm[169];
double *p = snorm;
*p = 1.0;
```

Case 2: I have no idea what the pointers are actualy doing so I don't know how to change this line to C#.

```
*(snorm+n) = *(snorm+n-1) * (double)(2*n-1) / (double)n;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First:

```
double[] snorm = new double[169];
snorm[0] = 1.0;
```

Than just use `snorm` instead of `p`.

Second:

```
snorm[n] = snorm[n-1] * (double)(2*n-1)/(double)n;
```

Basically `*p` means that you take the value at the address of memory, referenced by `p`. Incrementing and adding to the pointer are moving the pointer in memory, so `p++`, as well as `(p+1)` just refers to the next item in memory (how far it really moves in memory depends on the data type the pointer points to). And, `*(p+n)` is just a value of the n-th item in the array (if `p` points to an array)

Anyway, you should get yourself familiar with pointers.

Answer (score 3):

That code is basically using pointers as an alternative to array access. So your first snippet is equivalent to:

```
double[] snorm = new double[169];
snorm[0] = 1.0;
```

The next bit is equivalent to:

```
snorm[n] = snorm[n-1] * (double)(2*n-1) / (double)n;
```

(I'd use more spaces, but obviously that's a matter of taste.)

The only tricky bit is going to be if something *increments* a pointer - at that point you'll need to remember that you've basically got an extra offset to add to any future array indexes.